# fullcalendar - remove a dropped event after eventRender

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to add events to database using fullcalendar and I have succeeded in my approach. However after the event renders in the calendar there are two similar events. One that has been dropped and the other that has been rendered after successful ajax request.

Here is the code

```
drop: function(date, event) {
            var title = event.target.textContent;
            var start = date.format();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',response.eventblock,false);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                }
            });
            console.log(event);
        }
```

In the success block I've used renderEvent to add event to calendar. How do I remove the dropped event after successful ajax request?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, the way you are adding events is not recommended. Basically, you are adding a sourceless event which means you have to handle all of the automatic stuff manually.

But maybe you have a reason, idk.

To make it work, give your events IDs and then use `removeEvents` to "drop" them when one is added with the same id http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEvents/

```
success: function(response){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        'removeEvents', response.eventblock.id //or something like that
    );
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        'renderEvent', response.eventblock, false
    );
}
```

Comment: I got this working by using eventReceive and then update the event id.

Comment: then post your answer